# How do I target only certain elements with the same directive, without changing the markup?

Tags: angularjs, directive

I've been researching this for a few hours now.

Let's say I have a jQuery selector of $('#bottom .downloads .links a').click.....

How can I do the same type of thing in an Angular directive?

This is what I have so far and it works, but for all  tags on the page.

```
angular.module('directives', []).directive('a', function(mongoDB){ //Don't need ['customServices'], it can just be [] to use mongoDB
return {
    restrict : 'E',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs){     
    element.on('click', function(){
        //But this gets called for all links on the page
                //I just want it to be links within the #bottom .downloads .links div
                //I wanted to use a directive instead of ng-click="someMethod()"
    });
}
```

});

Is there a way to target this directive to only a certain div?  I guess I could change the restrict to 'C' or 'A' and add an attribute to the links, but I was wondering if I could still layout the front end like I currently am used to with my jQuery selectors.

Answer (score 5):

There is a pretty significant philosophical difference between AngularJS and jQuery. In jQuery, everything is in the DOM - including your data - and you do everything through DOM transformations. AngularJS, on the other hand, has separation of concerns built in: models, views, controllers, services, etc., are all separate. We use controllers to glue code together, but each component knows *nothing* about the other components.

So whereas in jQuery, one might use a selector to find all links matching a certain pattern and then add a certain functionality to it (say a click handler), in AngularJS, the HTML is the "offical record". Instead of abstracting away the attachment of a click handler into a JavaScript function, it is put right into the markup:

```html
<a ng-click="doWhatever()">Click me!</a>
```

In this case, `doWhatever` is a method on the scope for that part of the page, probably set in your controller:

```js
$scope.doWhatever = function () {
  console.log("Hello!");
}
```

So the way you are approaching the problem is not going to work in AngularJS. Instead, you need to look at directives not like jQuery selectors with a function, but as an **extension of HTML**. You ask yourself, "what does HTML not do out of the box that I need it to?" Your answer is your directive.

But AngularJS already has a built-in directive for click handlers (the `ngClick` used above).

Answer (score 1):

Angular already has an [a](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aa) directive, so you probably shouldn't create your own.

In an Angular world, to "target only a certain div" (well, <a> within the div) we declaratively target that <a> with a directive, rather than use CSS-like selectors.  So yes, restrict to 'A' and add an attribute to the <a> would be best:

```
<a ... target-this-one>...</a>
```

I personally think this reads better.  Looking at the HTML it is clear which <a>s have special/additional functionality.

As @Josh pointed out, you would only need to do this if ng-click isn't sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Yeah, I've been able to do the methods that both of you suggest.  I am just trying to find a way where I don't have to change the front end markup.  I found a way to kind of get it to work, but it's messy...after element.on('click', function(){ I do if($(element).parents('#bottom .downloads .links').length != 0).  I feel that with how smart Angular is, there must be a way to do it without marking up the HTML.

Comment: The reason I'm trying so hard to find an Angular solution is because I want to use my service(s) for these clicks.

Comment: @TJ, I think it is going to be difficult/messy if you want/have to reuse your existing markup.  Your solution looks reasonable -- I can't think of anything better.